# horizontal only webkit scrollbar style css

Tags: jquery, css, webkit

this is custom scrollbar in css

```css
 /* Gmail style scrollbar */
 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 12px
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   border-width: 1px 1px 1px 2px
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
   border-width: 0
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
   height: 16px;
   overflow: visible;
   width: 16px;
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
   height: 0;
   width: 0;
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
   background-clip: padding-box;
   border: solid transparent;
   border-width: 0 0 0 4px;
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal {
   border-width: 4px 0 0
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
   background-color: rgba(220, 172, 0, .05);
   box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(220, 172, 0, .1);
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(220, 172, 0, .1)
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track:active {
   background-color: rgba(220, 172, 0, .05);
   box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(220, 172, 0, .14), inset -1px 0 0 rgba(220, 172, 0, .07);
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal:active {
   box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(220, 172, 0, .14), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(220, 172, 0, .07)
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   background-color: rgba(220, 172, 0, .2);
   background-clip: padding-box;
   border: solid transparent;
   border-width: 1px 1px 1px 6px;
   min-height: 28px;
   padding: 100px 0 0;
   box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(220, 172, 0, .1), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(220, 172, 0, .07);
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
   border-width: 6px 1px 1px;
   padding: 0 0 0 100px;
   box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(220, 172, 0, .1), inset -1px 0 0 rgba(220, 172, 0, .07);
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
   background-color: rgba(220, 172, 0, .4);
   box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(220, 172, 0, .25);
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
   background-color: rgba(220, 172, 0, 0.5);
   box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px rgba(220, 172, 0, 0.35);
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
   border-width: 0 1px 0 6px
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal {
   border-width: 6px 0 1px
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
   background-color: rgba(220, 172, 0, .035);
   box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(220, 172, 0, .14), inset -1px -1px 0 rgba(220, 172, 0, .07);
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   border-width: 0 1px 0 6px
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
   border-width: 6px 0 1px
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
   background: transparent
 }
 body::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
   background-clip: padding-box;
   background-color: #f5f5f5;
   border: solid #fff;
   border-width: 0 0 0 3px;
   box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(220, 172, 0, .14), inset -1px 0 0 rgba(220, 172, 0, .07);
 }
 body::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:horizontal {
   border-width: 3px 0 0;
   box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(220, 172, 0, .14), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(220, 172, 0, .07);
 }
 body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   border-width: 1px 1px 1px 5px
 }
 body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
   border-width: 5px 1px 1px
 }
 body::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
   background-clip: padding-box;
   background-color: #f5f5f5;
   border: solid #fff;
   border-width: 3px 0 0 3px;
   box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(220, 172, 0, .14);
 }
```

```html
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris   placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus   enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis   luctus, metus</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris   placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus   enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis   luctus, metus</p>
```

I use the above code to beautify my scroll bar, but I do not want to style my vertical bar.

I tried to remove the tags which don't contain 'horizontal' but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 38):

For horizontal scroll bar set height

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Once you've set the css for

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{}
```

both the horizontal and vertical bars are automatically affected.

If you want the horizontal bar to look different from the vertical bar, you will have to set separate CSS for each, like this:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    background-color:#5B0B2B;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal:hover{
    background-color:#B31252;
    border: solid 1px #5B0B2B;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
    background-color:#2A8894;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical:hover {
    background-color:#32BFD1;
    border: solid 1px #2A8894;
}
```

Here's a complete [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/flamedenise/sdzeg8xq/).