# Horizontal scrollbar style is not applied

Tags: html, css

I'm using this code to style vertical and horizontal scrollbars but it only affects the vertical only.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
    border-radius:3px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713769/horizontal-only-webkit-scrollbar-style-css

Comment: Can you explain more? Because compare to the example, I don't see what's wrong with my code?