# Hiding horizontal scroll bar while keeping it active and keeping the vertical one

Tags: javascript, css

I need to hide the horizontal scroll bar without setting attr `overflow-x:hidden` and I don't want to hide the vertical one so `::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none};` is not an option. I tried setting `"height:0px"` but it also affects the vertical scrollbar. Is there any way of setting only horizontal scrollbar's display to none?

Comment: Here is another answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24405833/6117399

Comment: Does this answer your question? [horizontal only webkit scrollbar style css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713769/horizontal-only-webkit-scrollbar-style-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.inner {
  width: 200%;
}

.wrap::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/toszgwb6/